# AsyncTask Android. Возвращаемое значение не поддаётся сравнению

Tags: java, android, строки, android-asynctask, equals

Есть некий класс, который наследует `AsyncTask<>`.

```
class Sender<E> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Его переопределённый метод `doInBackground()`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.getOutputStream().write(new Gson().toJson(object).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        connection.connect();
        while ((read = connection.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
            byteStream.write(read);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteStream.toString();
}
```

Вот собственно в чём проблема:

При вызове метода `sender.get()`, я как и должно, получаю результат работы метода `doInBackground()`. Предположим, что это строка `"found"`, Вывел её на консоль, всё работает.
НО! При `sender.get().equals("found")` или `sender.get() == "found"` результат `false`. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас в ответе от сервера есть "невидимые" символы. Например невидимый пробел или перенос строки.

Проверить вы это можете, например, скопировав ответ сервера из консоли в к-л текстовый редактор с поддержкой отображения служебных символов, например `Notepad++`.

А решить это можно или поправив сервер или обрезав всё лишнее от ответа методом `String#trim()`

Т.е. вот так должно сработать:

```
sender.get().trim().equals("found")
```

---

P.S. `AsyncTask` устарел. Используйте, например, OkHttp/Retrofit/RxJava (особенно хороши они в соединении друг с другом) для сетевых запросов. Так же да - получать результат запроса через `get()` - странная идея. Это почти убивает смысл `AsyncTask`-a

Comment: Спасибо, у сервера в ответе был перенос строки, который я не заметил.